# Pass struct array to function with malloc

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'am writing a program where I need to add students to a array of structs.

Well, at the beginning I have the following struct array:

```
struct student *students[4];
```

After the declaration I add students like this to the array (just to have examples ...):

```
  students[0] = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
  students[0]->firstname = "Max";
  students[0]->secondname = "Taler";
  students[0]->number = 123456l;
```

...

Now I have to write a additional function, where I can pass the array as a parameter and add a new student.

So my function looks like this:

```
void add_student(struct student *students[],char *fristname, char *secondname, long number)
{
    int i=0;
    int new_position=0;
    int return_value = 0;
    // Search for the first available position for a new student 
    for(i=0; i<sizeof(students); i++)
    {
        if(students[i]==NULL)
        {
            new_position=i;
            return_value = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    struct student *new_student = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    students[new_position] = new_student;

    students[new_position]->fristname = fristname;
    students[new_position]->secondname = secondname;
    students[new_position]->number = number;

   return return_value; 
}
```

I call the function with this code:

```
add_student(students, "Anni", "Karls", 123232);
```

But now my **issue**: In my "add_student" function I get an array that has a strange structur: it includes itself as the first element and every other element is shifted by 1 element.

Cant figure out what the problem is ... Can somebody please help?

EDIT: Somebody asked me, how this can be. How the array can include "itself" as the first element.

Well, here are screenshots of the debugger (xCode):

Before entering "add_student":

[image: before entering "add_student"]

After entering "add_student" -> IN the function "add_student":

[image: after entering "add_student" -> IN the function "add_student"]

As you see, "students" has now 5 elements ...

Comment: `i<sizeof(students)` is not doing what you are expecting.

Comment: Note that contrary to your claim, you do *not* present a struct array in your code.  That would be an array whose elements are structs (which is permitted).  Instead, you present an array of pointers (to structs).

Comment: Note: `void add_student(...) { ... return return_value; }` is a problem.  `void` functions do not return values.

Comment: @chux Yeah sorry, I know that and this was only caused by "Copy&Paste" and translating in english :)

Answer (score 4):

Pass the length of the array to the function and change this

```
for(i=0; i<sizeof(students); i++)
```

to this

```
for(i=0; i<arrayLen; i++)
```

It seems you are inserting an element to some position in an array which has been allocated before hand; inserting is maybe more proper term than adding, but that is opinion.

You were applying `sizeof` operator on array type inside function - this will likely give you size of pointer in bytes because array name decays to pointer.

Comment: question: is sizeof(students) simply the size of a pointer on his/her machine

Comment: Nothing to guess about: that's exactly what it is, since `students` at this scope is nothing more than a pointer.

Comment: @mah: yep, added in the answer.

Comment: I've added the array length as a parameter. But I have still the problem, that the passed array somehow includes itself as the first element.

Comment: @MaxLebold: What do you mean "array includes itself as first element"? Also did you consider what happens if there is no available position for student in the array?

Comment: @MaxLebold, the passed array does not (and cannot) have the same data type as its elements, and therefore cannot include itself as an element.  Can you explain the problem you observe in different terms?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you for your answer. I've edited my question. :)

Comment: @MaxLebold: Did you remove return from void function? void function can't return value so you should remove that. Maybe you can take all the feedback here, incorporate it, and ask a new question with MCVE(http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I don't have Xcode, I doubt I will be able to reproduce your problem, in case that is Xcode related.

Comment: Hey @Giorgi now it works. I guess it was really a xCode related problem .. I've removed the "void" ... that was not the problem :) but thanks, all in all I can say, it was totally xCode related and only a visual problem of the "watches-view" of the debugger ...

Comment: Or you could have left void and removed return keyword. Good if it works now

Answer (score 0):

It's a little strange to statically allocate the array but then dynamically allocate the individual structures. You might consider dynamically allocating them all:

```
int num_students = 4;
struct student **students = malloc(sizeof(struct student) * num_students);
```

And then change your `add_student` function to look like this:

```
void add_student(struct student *students[], int arr_size, char *firstname, char *secondname, long number)
```